# Multi-label classification using fasttext with labels' probabilities summation not necessarily equals zero

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, multilabel-classification, fasttext

I followed [Multi-Label Classification documentation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#multi-label-classification) from [fasttext](https://fasttext.cc/) to apply it on my free text dataset which look like this after processing/labelling:

```
__label__nothing nothing
__label__choice __label__good-prices Inexpensive and large selection
__label__choice The wide range of products to choose from
__label__fast-delivery __label__choice great choice and fast delivery
__label__bad-prices sometimes also expensive
__label__choice The wide range of products
__label__nothing there is nothing especially
.
.
.
```

I set up a notebook instance on AWS SageMaker and train the model. For simplicity, let's say with *5 labels* (**choice**, **fast-delivery**, **good-prices**, **bad-prices**, **nothing**), the problem is when I predict some text with sitting the (**K**) to **-1** to get all of them, I always get the summation probabilities of labels is equal to **100%**, for example:

```
wide range of products as well as fast delivery
```

I expect something like:

> **choice** (95%) **fast-delivery** (95%) **good-prices** (10%) **bad-prices** (5%) **nothing** (10%)

and then I could set the threshold to greater than 50% so only 2 labels matches (**choice** and **fast-delivery**)

instead I got something like:

> **choice** (40%) **fast-delivery** (40%) **good-prices** (5%) **bad-prices** (5%) **nothing** (10%)

which means if the text really matches the 5 labels so much it will return 20% for each, and will be dismissed all by the threshold.

*N.B.: in the documentation's example the got the output as expected but by following the docs it's not working like that:*

[image]

The question is how could I achieve the output as expected? within fasttext or even with some other tool, is there some parameters to change/add?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [fasttext documentation](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#multi-label-classification), you can get multi-label probabilities that don't sum to 1 if you use the `-loss one-vs-all` or `-loss ova` options.